# user_meta table in staging vs live site

Tags: users

I copied a site over from live to staging and in the process of updating the site users on the LIVE site have updated their information (ie email and passwords).  Is it as easy as copying the user_meta table over to the staging site and the new passwords will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are stored in users not usermeta. I'd copy both tables over and it'll work fine.

```
 `wp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
  KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
)
```